# Is client connected on XBee s6b

Tags: xbee

I have an XBee S6B setup in wireless access mode and physically connected to a Raspberry PI. I connect my laptop to the XBee WiFi access point and I can send data back and forth between the Raspberry PI and the XBee over WiFi.

Can someone tell me if there is a way for the Raspberry PI to know that the laptop has successfully connected or disconnected? Are there any commands the Raspberry PI can send to the XBee to establish if something has connected/disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no Node Join frame, but if it’s in Access Point mode then you could just periodically ping the other device. You would know its address since there can’t be more than one external device in AP mode.

Comment: If I was using an s2b devices in a zigbee mesh,  would I be able to identify if the xbee was properly connected to the mesh? I.e. Had sight of the controller?

Comment: The Association Indicator (AI) tells you whether you've joined to a network. On a coordinator, it indicates successful network creation. In both instances, you'd need an extra technique to know when other devices join to the network.